# c# UDP to the client on the subnet

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, udp

I'm developing the multiplayer infrastructure of a game.
I am using C# language and udp protocol.

I have a server (amazon aws) and I can send data to the server and process it on the server.
But when I send data from server to client, the client does not receive any data. It is not because of udp drop.

The client is on a subnet.
Target (random example) public ip:12.12.12.12 client is in its subnet.
Client ip in lan:192.168.1.7

How can I address it?
How can I get it from server to destination properly.

```
static void send(string message)
{
    try
    {
        UdpClient udpserver = new UdpClient(targetIp, targetPort);

        Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        udpserver.SendAsync(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length);

        udpserver.Close();
        cont();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: -> [Hole punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking)) and in your specific case [UDP hole punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching)

Comment: You can use a TCP connection, where the connection must be established by the client side. The server can then respond to requests.